# CA3140 wideband output amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, bandwidth, slew-rate, gain-bandwidth-product

The following circuit is nearly exactly what I need for the output stage of my function generator:

[image]

datasheet: https://www.renesas.com/us/en/www/doc/datasheet/ca3140-a.pdf

What I don't understand is how an op-amp with GBP = 4.5 MHz and slew rate = 9 V/us, followed by a unity gain buffer, could possibly have an overall nominal bandwidth of 10 MHz and SR = 28 V/us, *especially* in a gain of 10 configuration. What am I missing here?

Comment: Opamp gain is open loop, then it is further amplified with transistor pair, then feed back with an attenuator 1:9.  It is not clear what is the input voltage range VS. output voltage range 18Vpp. How do you know that overall gain is G=10?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Transistor pair doesn't amplify, just buffers. Gain of 10 comes from noninverting configuration with 1:9 attenuator, as you said.

Comment: Therefore the opamp gain is 20dB and the BW is only 0.3MHz. Probably the 10MHz BW is referring at transistor buffer stage.